# Freeform: Custom field value not showing up in subject

Tags: solspace-freeform

I've read a lot about this online and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

- I have created a custom field.
- In my form I set that custom field to a variable. I've confirmed in
  the Chrome Dev Console that the field (a hidden text box) is showing
  up and has a value of the variable.
- The notifications panel says that I can use custom variables for the
  subject. However, it doesn't seem to matter it continues to display
  the variable tags and name e.g. {my_custom_variable}.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have the custom field in your composer template as well as your custom template. Otherwise, Freeform doesn't bring that field into the notification context.

Comment: T h a n k - y o u !